# body parameters not documented while using express-oas-generator

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a question, I defined my route and I know I need to some parameters in body but I do not know how to define/show these parameters on doc.

This is my route;

```
router.post('/login', errorHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const loginResult = await UserService.login({ username, password });
    if (loginResult) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        ...loginResult
      });
    }
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ success: false, msg: 'Incorrect username or password' });
  })
);
```

And I used advanced implementation of generator;

```
expressOasGenerator.handleResponses(app, {
  predefinedSpec: (spec) => {
    _.set(spec, 'info', options.swaggerDefinition.info);
    _.set(spec, 'mongooseModels', mongoose.modelNames());
    _.set(spec, 'components.securitySchemes.bearerAuth', {
      type: 'http',
      scheme: 'bearer',
      bearerFormat: 'JWT'
    });
    _.set(spec, "paths['/v1/some-path'].get.security", [{ bearerAuth: [] }]);
    return spec;
  },
  mongooseModels: mongoose.modelNames(),
  alwaysServeDocs: true
});

...
createRoutes(app);

...

expressOasGenerator.handleRequests();
app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`App running on port ${port}`);
});
```

But on the localthost:3000/api-docs I can't see the body parameters, how can I define and show on doc those parameters? Can someone help me?